# Can't import tensorflow, OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to install TensorFlow for python (3.7) using anaconda.
I've installed the Cuda 10.2 and the matching cndd and installed it in a virtual environment:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```

The command ran without any errors, but when i try to import it in python I get:

```
    Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\abual\Anaconda3\envs\ml1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\abual\Anaconda3\envs\ml1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 959, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\abual\Anaconda3\envs\ml1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\abual\Anaconda3\envs\ml1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\abual\Anaconda3\envs\ml1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\abual\Anaconda3\envs\ml1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\abual\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\abual\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\abual\Anaconda3\envs\ml1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>>>
```

Can anyone help me solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have installed the 32-bit TensorFlow package while your machine requires a 64-bit installation ( or vice-versa ) ?

Comment: I did pip install tensorflow==2.1.0, How to install the 64 bit version?

Comment: Actually, It did work for me after creating another environment with python 3.8, but I've got another problem, which is when I try to run tensorflow.Session() I get an: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'.

Answer (score 0):

**On your 1st question**

The problem might be installing 32 bit on a 64-bit machine., try installing a 64 bit TensorFlow version  2.x.
Kindly refer to the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

**On your 2nd  question**

The tf.Session() is on the version 1.x, you need to migrate it to 2.1. 
You can read about migration [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

Kindly refer to the sample code below

```
# Using the `close()` method.
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.run(...)
sess.close()
```